# Team Foundation, Groups and Work Items

Tags: tfs, grouping, workitem

I'm looking for some guidance and reassurance, I'm working on a TFS Website that'll be used for  Programmers and Clients to keep track of Tasks they've created or are working on. The idea of what it should be is a central place that both clients and programmers would use without having to travel to far within the website itself.

Example, I have John and Stewart, they are both Programmers, then I have Many and Tom which are Clients (Many belongs to New York and Tom belongs to California).

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║Programmers ║  New York   ║  California ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ John       ║ Many        ║ Tom         ║
║ 2 ║ Stewart    ║             ║             ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

What I'm thinking is splitting this up into groups, 'Programmers', 'New York', 'California' (There is more than just two clients). Then, in theory, when someone logs in depending on what group they belong to.

- Programmers will be able to see the Work Items assigned to them or all.
- Clients would only be able to see the Work Items that belong to it, so if a User that belongs to New York logged in they would be shown only Work Items that are part of New York and nothing more.

I'd like to know if this is possible, and if so how would I be able to achieve this? If more information is needed, please do ask.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the requirement can be achieved via defining different teams in TFS.

I understand your requirement that your Programmers and Clients actually need collaboration to work together. Let's say, for example, one client may give some feedbacks to programmers that whether a bug is fixed; programmers track their tasks or feature requests which are submitted by client and etc. So, for your scenario, you **should create two teams**. One is for New York (team members: John, Stewart, Many); and another one is for California (team members: John, Stewart, Tom). Each team can work independently on its own backlog, defined by its area path, unrelated to the other team's work.

When you create a team, you can create one Area Path for the team, so the team will work on that specific area. You can grand user permissions on the Area level, so New York client can only check work items in New York area; while California client can only check work items in California area.

Please check the following links about work with Teams in TFS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500414.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306083.aspx